# Configure wifi on raspberry-pi using it as a BLE perpheral

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, bluez, bleno

I have to develop an iOS app which connects to raspberry-pi via bluetooth and configures RPi's wifi to connect to a particular ssid. The ssid and password is provided from the app via bluetooth.

Is this possible to do? I am wondering if its possible to execute commands on RPi received from the app.

Similarly we need to do it using Android.
Can we achieve this using Bleno and Bluez on the pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the Pi via Bluetooth. You need a service running on the Pi and waiting for a device to establish a Bluetooth connection. This can either be a python or any other server-side script.

In your App, you connect to this service using Bluetooth and execute different commands to connect to the wifi.
[See this site for more information on how to connect a pi to a wifi network.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)

Comment: I eventually used nodejs and bleno package to create a service and handle the writes